# Why am I facing an overflow error only with the debugger?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub backsolve_straddle()
    Dim f_x As Double
    Dim dydx As Double
    Dim d1 As Double
    Dim d2 As Double
    Dim N_d1 As Double
    Dim N_d2 As Double
    Dim spot As Double
    Dim strike As Double
    Dim vol As Double
    Dim r As Double
    Dim tenor As Double
    Dim prem As Double
    Dim ea As Double
    Dim xr As Double
    Dim xi As Double
    Dim N_d1_neg As Double
    Dim N_d2_neg As Double
 
    spot = Worksheets("Straddle").Cells(3, 9)
    tenor = Worksheets("Straddle").Cells(5, 9)
    vol = Worksheets("Straddle").Cells(6, 9)
    r = Worksheets("Straddle").Cells(7, 9)
    prem = Worksheets("Straddle").Cells(8, 9)
    xi = Worksheets("Straddle").Cells(3, 11)
 
    ea = 100
    Do While ea > 1
        d1 = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Ln(spot / xi) + (tenor * (r + (vol ^ 2 / 2)))) / (vol * (tenor ^ 0.5))
        d2 = d1 - (vol * (tenor ^ 0.5))
        N_d1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(d1, True)
        N_d2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(d2, True)
        N_d1_neg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(-d1, True)
        N_d2_neg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Norm_S_Dist(-d2, True)
        
        f_x = spot * N_d1 - (xi * Exp(-r * tenor) * N_d2) + (xi * Exp(-r * tenor) * N_d2_neg) - (spot * N_d1_neg) - prem
        dydx = N_d1 - N_d1_neg
        
        xr = xi - (f_x / dydx)
        ea = Abs((xr - xi) / xr)
        xi = xr
    Loop
    Worksheets("Straddle").Cells(4, 9) = xr
 End Sub
```

I get the overflow error after the `Do While` line of code. Essentially, I'm using the debugger and when I enter the `Do While` loop, I get an overflow error. However, I don't get this error when I add a breakpoint at the end of the code and just skip to that point to the run the code. Can anyone guide me on why? I'm using Excel VBA on Mac if that makes a difference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which exact line gives you the error? Put a breakp oint and check the values of the variables there.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'm guessing it's the line after `Do While`. This is because the overflow error comes up and in locals window, ea has the value of 100.

Comment: No need to guess.. step through the code and you will get the exact ine which is giving you the error

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes i did exactly that but I'm not sure why the error is occurring. Usually overflow errors occur when the data type doesn't match the number given. However, I don't think this is the case so would like some guidance on what could be wrong.

Comment: Put a break point on `Do While ea > 1` and then press `F8`. and then go through each line, one by one.